# Plotting Graph with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a csv file that I want to create graphs from using specific groups.  My csv file looks like this:

```
Year    County      Item        Value
1989    BILLINGS    BARLEY      6000
1989    GOLDEN      CORN        1700
1989    SLOPE       FLAXSEED    100
1990    BILLINGS    BARLEY      15000
1990    GOLDEN      CORN        300
1990    SLOPE       FLAXSEED    500
```

I want to make a graph of the Value for BARLEY, CORN and FLAXSEED per county through time (i.e. from 1989 to 1990.  So there would be 3 separate graphs for each county and in each graph are three lines one each for barley, corn and flaxseed and their respective values per year.

The code I am trying to use is:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='Item',col="County", margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.pointplot, "Year", "Value", color=".3", ci=None);
```

but this returns the error `Could not convert to numeric`

Using excel I have changed my datatypes to general for `County` and `Item` and number for `Year` and `Value` but that doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I just did a quickie test of this and worked OK for me.  I imagine you are reading year/value as non-numbers and it's not getting converted by seaborn automatically.  Changing stuff around in excel is not going to help.  You need to do it in pandas.  Instead of showing the csv, show the data AFTER reading into pandas and show results of ```df.info()```.  Or just do ```df.Year = df.Year.astype(int)``` and same for 'Value'.

Comment: hmm, I just tried that and even after changing Year and Value to int it says `Data columns (total 4 columns):
Year         166 non-null int32
County       166 non-null object
Item          166 non-null object
Value        166 non-null object
dtypes: int32(1), object(3)`

Comment: nevermind, there were a couple blank cells in my real file I had to remove and that seemed to have fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: in my ipython env I just got what you have expected.